# Secure NServiceBus Transport

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possible to have secure (SSL/TLS) connectivity to NServiceBus from the web application? The scenario is, the web application (ASP.NET) will be hosted in the DMZ and the Service Bus will be behind the internal firewall. But the connectivity from the web server to the service bus should be secure because of the high secure nature of the application.

Comment: Which transport are you using? MSMQ? SQL? RabbitMq?

Comment: Planning to use RabbitMQ

Answer (score 3):

NServiceBus supports different kind of transports. For example, [RabbitMQ has support for SSL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html). Other transports could be inherently cloud related, which means you can communicate over SSL but communication leaves the datacenter.

On the other hand, you can also [encrypt your NServiceBus messages](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/security/encryption). Perhaps this is something that's useful to you?